# Running a Spring MVC app in tomcat 7.0 gives me HTTP Status 404 : requested resource is not available.

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm trying to debug this for the last 2 days. As there are a number of similar questions on stackoverflow. But I'm not able to find a solution.

I'm trying to execute a Spring MVC CRUD project. When I run the app, I get the `Error 404: The requested resource (/SpringMyPersonalDiary/user) is not available.`

My structure is as follows:

[image]

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SpringMyPersonalDiary</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.smithak" />


    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

UserController.java

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public String setupForm(Map<String, Object> map) {
        User user = new User();
        map.put("user", user);
        map.put("userList", userService.getAllUsers());
        return "user";
    }

    // We might not need delete & edit
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doActions(@ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map) {

        User userResult = new User();
        switch (action.toLowerCase()) {// Only in Java 7 we can put string in
                                        // switch statement
        case "add":
            userService.add(user);
            userResult = user;
            break;
        case "delete":
            userService.delete(user.getId());
            userResult = new User();
            break;
        case "edit":
            userService.edit(user);
            userResult = user;
            break;
        case "search":
            User searchedUser = userService.getUser(user.getId());
            userResult = searchedUser != null ? searchedUser : new User();
            break;
        }
        map.put("user", userResult);
        map.put("userList", userService.getAllUsers());
        return "user";
    }
}
```

error
[image]

Can anyone please help me debug this issue. 
Any help from would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Check the server logs.

Comment: Why is your mapping `"/user.do"` instead of `"/user"`?

Comment: @geoand: I have a mapping "/user" for setupForm()

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the `GET` mapping

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: I'm new to this. Could you please tell me where I could locate the server logs?

Comment: Have you tried changing `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`?

Comment: @geoand: I tried it just now. But I'm getting the same error :(

Comment: How are you starting Tomcat? Then we can tell you where the logs are.

Comment: @david: I have configured the Tomcat 7.0 server in Eclipse. I do a right click on the server there and start tomcat.

Comment: In that case I'm not exactly sure. Does your application doesn't have logging, e.g. log4j? You can also check in `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.28\logs` or where ever your Tomcat is installed. You should be able to find somewhere in your Eclipse prefs where actually Tomcat installed on the filesystem.

Comment: @david: I checked the logs in my tomcat folder and they are blank files. But I found this issue in my console. Web app root system property already set to different value: 'webapp.root' Choose unique values for the 'webAppRootKey' context-param in your web.xml files!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue. 
Thanks to @david for helping me debug.

I was actually missing the `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `log4j.xml` inside my `src/main/resources` folder.
By looking at the errors in my console I was able to fix this. 
The errors were as follows:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

Hope this helps some amateur like me. :)